# Picture-in-picture (PiP) feature on chromecast custom receiver

Tags: html5-video, chromecast

I'm trying to create a custom receiver with picture-in-picture feature. I did a viability test creating a simple custom receiver with two html 5 video tags, one for main screen and other for PiP screen. However, just the main video worked. I debugged the receiver, but there is no error message.

Does anyone know if Chromecast have some restriction that allows to show just one video one screen?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have more than one active Video element.

Comment: Thank you for the info.  


In my testing, additional video tags they will fire a *MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED* event when you run the load method on the media element.  


@Ali Naddaf, is there a way to deactivate a video element without deleting it entirely? Pausing it does not work.